# Regex replace word between some character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need our help for my regex replace.
I need to replace one word OR one sentence between with preg_replace in php

- start by . or , or whitespace or nothing
- and end by . or , or ! or ? or : or ; or whitespace

But my regex don't work : :(

```
"/^(?:\s|\.|,)($sWord)(?:\s|\.|,|\!|\?|\:|;)$/"
```

Tried:

```
$sContent = preg_replace("/^(?:\s|\.|,)($sWord)(?:\s|\.|,|\!|\?|\:|;)$/",
                         '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . htmlspecialchars($sDefinition) . '">' . $sWord . '</a>', 
                         $sContent);
```

Comment: $sContent = preg_replace("/^(?:\s|\.|,)($sWord)(?:\s|\.|,|\!|\?|\:|;)$/", '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . htmlspecialchars($sDefinition) . '">' . $sWord . '</a>', $sContent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is [anchored](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to the start and end of the *entire* input string (`^` and `$` at the start/end of your regex). You need to remove those for the regex to work.

Then, for single character alternatives, it's better to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead of alternation:

```
"/[\s.,]($sWord)[\s.,!?:;]/"
```

If you need to keep the delimiting characters for the replace operation, enclose them in a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
"/([\s.,])($sWord)([\s.,!?:;])/"
```

which you can then use in your replacement string as `$1` etc.:

```
$sContent = preg_replace("/([\s.,])($sWord)([\s.,!?:;])/",
                         '$1<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . htmlspecialchars($sDefinition) . '">$2</a>$3', 
                         $sContent);
```

Comment: Yes it's work but for my replace i need to keep the first (\s.,) and the last charactere (\s.,!?:;)

Comment: @user3337165: Your previous regex didn't preserve them either - but you can easily change that using [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: why i don't understand "/(?:\s|\.|,)($sWord)(?:\s|\.|,|\!|\?|\:|;)/" or "/[?:\s|\.|,]($sWord)[?:\s|\.|,|\!|\?|\:|;]/" don't keep my ' , ' after my word

Comment: Did you read the documentation about capturing groups I linked to?